# Is there a difference between passing an image vs. its raw data

Tags: python, image, numpy, image-processing, computer-vision

Say I have some image I would like to pass to my algorithm. I came across the [tobytes()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tobytes.html) function in Python, of which the description is clear.

I'm however unclear what the difference would be if I pass the image as raw data rather than in its original array form. Are there applications for instance where someone might need to only pass the raw data?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`tobytes()` is for when you need a python `bytes` object - perhaps you want to write the raw data to a file, or send it over a TCP socket. Files and sockets don't know about anything other than series of bytes.

Or maybe you want to `pickle` your data, but the computer you read it on doesn't have numpy.

---

It's also handy for inspecting the in-memory representation of `float` or `int` objects:

```
>>> np.array(1.0).bytes()
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf0?'
```

But arguably that's better to do as:

```
>>> np.array(1.0).view((np.uint8, 8)) 
array([  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 240,  63], dtype=uint8)
```

Answer (score 0):

Passing the raw data means you don't know the image sizes any more, just the number of bytes occupied by its pixels. Was it a 1024x800 image or a 1600x512 image?

You also loose type information: unless the image originally had 8-bit pixel values, each pixel will be "split" across multiply bytes (e.g. 4 bytes for a floating-point value).

That is to say, it'd be a bad idea to pass raw bytes to a function. You'd have to define your function to make assumptions about the data (e.g. 8-bit square image), which you cannot test for. And what would the advantage be?

However, raw data might be interesting to push into a compression algorithm (e.g. zip), to save the image data to file. You would write the image information to file (size, data type), then the compressed raw byte stream. But all of this would be happening inside one function, you wouldn't pass the raw bytes to the function.